# how to use groovyUtils.getXmlHolder() to modify the XML using XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath, groovy

I need to open a Xml from a path and then modify the node values using Groovy scripting... How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i referred these 2 links to make it work

http://soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/tips-a-tricks.html#5-change-a-request-xml-from-groovy

http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/support/GroovyUtils.html